# Sequence of numbers recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

A sequence of real numbers $$ u_1, u_2, u_3... $$ satisfies $$u_1=1$$ and the recurrence relation $$4u_{n+1}=au_n-2$$ for all positive integers n where a is a real constant. Express $$u_n$$ in terrms of a and n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a first order linear recurrence relation. It's solved as first order differential equations with constant coefficients:

- First solve the linear recurrence without constant term: $u_{n+1}=\dfrac a4\,u_n$,
- Look for one particular solution of the complete linear recurrence. This should be a constant if $a\neq 4$,
- Examine the particular case $a=4$.

Comment: The linear recurrence without constant term would just be a geometric of progression of common ratio $$a/4$$ isn't it? That means the solution is $$(a/4)^{n-1}$$. I don't know how to deal with the constant term though

Comment: You call it $C$, and replace in the linear relation: you'll get a linear equation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try writing out the first few terms of the sequence, in terms of $a$.

Comment: This is true only if $a=4$.